# Question on limit definitions

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

I am trying to comprehend the epsilon-delta proofs and additive limit laws proofs and I have reached the following conclusions (A,B). If anyone could verify that my understanding on either is correct it would be very appreciated.

**A**. Let functions $f(x), t(x)$ with the same domain. Let $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = K$ and let $|f(x)-K|\ge|t(x)-T|$ for all $x$ in the domain. Show that $lim_{x\rightarrow a}t(x) = T$.

Proof:

Since $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = K$ we have that:

For any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t. if $\;0<|x-a|<\delta\;$ then $\;|f(x)-K|<\epsilon$

Since $|f(x)-K|\ge|t(x)-T|$ for all $x$ in the domain we have that:

For any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t. if $\;0<|x-a|<\delta\;$ then $\;|t(x)-T|<\epsilon$

Thus we reach:
$lim_{x\rightarrow a}t(x) = T$

I understand this result as: anytime you want to show that $lim_{x\rightarrow a}t(x) = T$ it suffices to find any function $f(x)$ on the same domain, with $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = K$ and the property $|f(x)-K|\ge|t(x)-T|$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Is this correct? If so, can it be made to be more precise, i.e. does the property need to hold for all $x$ in the domain?

**B.** Let functions $f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x), t(x)$ with the same domain and $n$ finite.

Let $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_i(x) = K_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and let $\sum_{i=1}^n|f(x)-K_i|\ge|t(x)-T|$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Show that $lim_{x\rightarrow a}t(x) = T$.

Proof:

Since $lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_i(x) = K_i$ we have that:

For given $\;\epsilon/n\;$ there exists $\;\delta_1>0\;$ s.t. if $\;0<|x-a|<\delta_1\;$ then $\;|f_1(x)-K_1|<\epsilon/n$

$\vdots$

For given $\;\epsilon/n\;$ there exists $\;\delta_n>0\;$ s.t. if $\;0<|x-a|<\delta_n\;$ then $\;|f_n(x)-K_n|<\epsilon/n$

Let $\delta=min(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_n)$. We need to show that:
if $\;0<|x-a|<\delta\;$ then $\;|t(x)-T|<\epsilon\;$

Since $0<|x-a|<\delta\le\delta_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$, all the following hold:

$\;|f_1(x)-K_1|<\epsilon/n\;$ and $\;|f_2(x)-K_2|<\epsilon/n\;$  and $\;\dots\;$ and $\;|f_n(x)-K_n|<\epsilon/n\;$

Thus if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n|f_i(x)-K_i|<\epsilon$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n|f_i(x)-K_i|\ge|t(x)-T|$ for all $x$ in the domain we have that:

if $\;0<|x-a|<\delta\;$ then $\;|t(x)-T|<\epsilon$

Thus we reach:
$lim_{x\rightarrow a}t(x) = T$

Comment: (A) is correct. You only need the assumption for all $x$ near $a$, not everywhere. I haven't read (B) but it's probably OK.

Comment: The property (I assume you mean $|f(x) - K| \ge |t(x) - T|$) need only hold for $x$ in some neighborhood of $a$. Limits do not care what a function does somewhere else - only what occurs in the immediate environs of the point have any impact on the.

Comment: Result (A) is just a special case of the squeeze theorem (If $f(x)\le g(x) \le h(x)$ in some neighborhood of $a$ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} h(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = $). In this case we have $-|f(x) - K| \le t(x) - T \le |f(x) - K|$, and because $f \to K$ as $x\to a$, the left and right hand functions go to $0$, so the center does as well. So I would suggest proving the squeeze theorem by epsilon-delta proof, then use it to prove (A) and (B) - which is a special case of (A).